# How do I customize the message for Azure AD B2C multifactor authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

The current/default text message

```
123456
Use this code for my_policy verification.
```

I would like to have a message specific to our company such as this:

```
123456
Use the above code to authenticate your "My Company" online account.
```

I can't seem to find an option to do that in the Azure Portals (new and classic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are unable to customise the screen via the policy editor in the portal then it's either not supported during the preview or requires a support request (similar to if you wish to customise the email delivered for verification purposes).